# Random matrix properties

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, random-matrices

Let $\mathbf{H}_{N,K}$ be a random matrix whose entries are i.i.d complex Gaussian random variables with variance $1$. Then, we know from the law of large number that if $N,K\rightarrow\infty$, we have
$$\frac{1}{N}\mathbf{H}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{H}\rightarrow\mathbf{I},$$
where $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. Now, I have some questions regarding this large dimension analysis:
Let define $\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{H}^\mathrm{H}\mathbf{H}$. If $f$ be a continues function, is it true to write?
$$f(\mathbf{A})\rightarrow f(\mathbf{\mathbb{E}[\mathbf{A}]})=f(N\mathbf{I}).$$
More over, can we write as follows?
$$\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}f(\mathbf{A})\mathbf{H}\rightarrow \mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}f(N\mathbf{I})\mathbf{H},$$
and for special case $f(\mathbf{A})=\mathbf{A}$, we have?
$$\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{A}\mathbf{H}\rightarrow N\mathbf{H}^{\mathrm{H}}\mathbf{H}\rightarrow N^2\mathbf{I}.$$

Comment: I don't see how this would be consistent with [Marchenko-Pastur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marchenko–Pastur_distribution)

Comment: Your identity matrix $\mathbf I$ must be $K\times K$ and hence cannot be the limit of anything as $K\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let me check this for real matrices and $f(A)={\rm tr}\,A^2$. The $N$ eigenvalues $\mu_n$ of $A$ have in the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$ at fixed $N/K=\lambda\leq 1$ the Marchenko-Pastur distribution 
$$\rho(\mu)=\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{n=1}^N\delta(\mu-\mu_n)\right]=N\frac{\sqrt{\lambda_+-\mu/N}\sqrt{\mu/N-\lambda_-}}{2\pi\lambda\mu},\;\;\lambda_-<\mu/N<\lambda_+,$$
with $\lambda_\pm=(1\pm\sqrt\lambda)^2$. The function $f(A)$ tends in this limit to
$$f(A)\rightarrow\int_{N\lambda_-}^{N\lambda_+}\mu^2\rho(\mu)\,d\mu=N^3(1+\lambda),$$
which differs from the answer $f(N I)=N^3$ conjectured in the OP.